# How to retrieve certificate from a keyvault and import it into another without saving it?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault

In an Azure pipeline there are following tasks

1. AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3 deploys a Key Vault from an ARM template
2. Then a AzurePowerShell@5 checks if the Key vault contains a "my-self-signed-cert" and if not - imports it into the Key Vault
3. Finally another AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3 deploys a Service Fabric cluster and configures the SF cluster and its VMSS to use the certificate

Here are the tasks:

```
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  displayName: 'Deploy Keyvault'
  inputs:
    deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
    subscriptionId: '${{ parameters.SubscriptionId }}'
    azureResourceManagerConnection: '${{ parameters.ArmConnection }}'
    action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
    resourceGroupName: '${{ parameters.resourceGroupName }}'
    location: 'West Europe'
    templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
    csmFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/pipelines/templates/keyvault.json'
    csmParametersFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/pipelines/templates/keyvault-params.json'
    deploymentMode: 'Incremental'

- task: ARM Outputs@5
  displayName: 'Collect Keyvault output'
  inputs:
    ConnectedServiceNameSelector: 'ConnectedServiceNameARM'
    ConnectedServiceNameARM: '${{ parameters.ArmConnection }}'
    resourceGroupName: '${{ parameters.resourceGroupName }}'
    whenLastDeploymentIsFailed: 'fail'

- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  displayName: 'Import certificate'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '${{ parameters.ArmConnection }}'
    ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
    azurePowerShellVersion: '3.1.0'
    Inline: |
      $Cert = Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName my-kv -Name my-self-signed-cert
      if (!$Cert) {
          $Base64 = 'MIIWMgIBA___3000_chars_here____o7WqDoWm5I7fg=='
          $Cert = Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName my-kv -Name my-self-signed-cert -CertificateString $Base64
      }
      # set the pipeline variables Thumbprint and SecretId - needed for SF deployment
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Thumbprint]$($Cert.Thumbprint)"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SecretId]$($Cert.SecretId)"

# deploy SF cluster by ARM template and use the SF Cluster certificate thumbsprint as admin cert
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  displayName: 'Deploy SF cluster'
  inputs:
    deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
    subscriptionId: '${{ parameters.SubscriptionId }}'
    azureResourceManagerConnection: '${{ parameters.ArmConnection }}'
    action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
    resourceGroupName: '${{ parameters.resourceGroupName }}'
    location: 'West Europe'
    templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
    csmFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/pipelines/templates/sfcluster.json'
    csmParametersFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/pipelines/templates/sfcluster-params.json'
    overrideParameters: '-certificateThumbprint $(Thumbprint) -sourceVaultResourceId $(KeyvaultId) -certificateUrlValue $(SecretId)'
    deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
```

This works well, but now I am trying to replace the self-signed certificate by a real certificate, hosted at another Key Vault.

My plan is to download the new certificate contents (including the key) from the other Key Vault, then Base64-encode it (to avoid creating any temporary files) - and finally `Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate ... -CertificateString $Base64` into my Key Vault (see the "Step 2" in my list of tasks).

My problem is that I am stuck in retrieving the certificate contents.

I am able to retrieve the "real" certificate with the following PowerShell commands:

```
$Cert = Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName the-company-kv -Name the-real-cert
$Secret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName the-company-kv -Name the-real-cert
```

They above commands return some metadata, but there is nothing resembling the contents that I would be able to (if not already base64-encoded):

```
$Base64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($Bytes)
Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName my-kv -Name my-self-signed-cert -CertificateString $Base64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a solution for how to copy a certificate from one Key Vault to another (here: the-company-kv -> my-kv) without saving it into a temporary file:

```
$Cert = Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName my-kv -Name the-real-cert
if (!$Cert) {
    $OrigCert = Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName the-company-kv -Name the-real-cert
    $Secret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName the-company-kv -Name $OrigCert.Name
    $Cert = Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName my-kv -Name $OrigCert.Name -CertificateString $Secret.SecretValueText
}
```

I didn't realize, that PowerShell is not showing all properties, when I enter `$Secret` at the command prompt and thus I didn't see the `$Secret.SecretValueText` at first.